# C#: How can I POST data to a page redirected by an earlier POST?

Tags: c#, post, web, webrequest, webresponse

I am using c# to accomplish the following:

1. Post data to a page (using HttpWebRequest).
2. Get the response (redirected to another page by the posted data).
3. **Post the further data to the response page**.

I am able to accomplish the first 2 steps, but I cannot get the 3rd step to work because it always takes me back to the beginning page. I have tried using a `CookieCollection` and transferring the cookies from the first request to the second, but it did not solve the problem. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean without code and data. Capture a request made from the browser using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp), then compare what your application sends.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with PostBackUrl

```
<asp:button id="Button2"
      text="Post value to another page" 
      postbackurl="PostBackUrlPage.aspx" 
      runat="Server">
</asp:button>
```